# Acceso a propiedad de constructor php

Tags: php

¿Por qué no se accede a la propiedad "ruedas" en esta clase Coche? La línea "echo $renault->ruedas;" no muestra el valor que se ha asignado. ¿Ya no es válida está manera de acceder a las propiedades?

```
class Coche{
        var $ruedas;
        function Coche(){ //Metodo constructor
            $this->ruedas=4;
        }
        function arrancar(){
            echo "arrancando<br>";
        }
    }

    $renault=new Coche();
    $renault->arrancar();
    echo $renault->ruedas;
```

Comment: El método constructor no puede tener el mismo nombre de la clase, hace mucho que eso dejó de funcionar, solo cambia `function Coche()` por `public function __construct()` y, de preferencia, declara la variable con la visibilidad deseada (public, private o protected). Si estás siguiendo un tutorial, asegúrate que sea válido para PHP 5.4 o posterior.

Comment: En mi caso el código funciona, y puedo ver las 4 ruedas del `Coche`. Pero como bien dice @Triby, estás implementando prácticas obsoletas, tanto con respecto al constructor, como con respecto al uso de `var` para definir al miembro `ruedas` de la clase. Revisa [la documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.properties.php) con mucha atención, hay varias cosas que te conciernen. Convendría que leas también [sobre los constructores](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.decon.php).

Comment: Si se puede ver si usas __construct() como apunta Triby pero mi pregunta era si la antigua manera de acceder ha quedado totalmente obsoleta.

Comment: @RicardoKra, parece que sigue funcionando, pero podrías obtener un mensaje `E_DEPRECATED` y, en caso de usar nombres de espacio, definitivamente no va a funcionar ese constructor. Lee los enlaces que te proporcionaron, ahí hay más información al respecto.

Comment: Los constructores con el mismo nombre de la clase existían en PHP 4, ya desde PHP 5 (año 2004) empezó a usarse `__construct()` en su lugar (estamos hablando de 18 años), lo único que justificaría el uso de tu código es que debas **por algún motivo justificado** mantener un proyecto funcionando en PHP 4, cuyo soporte, por cierto, [fue descontinuado en 2008](https://www.php.net/releases/index.php).

Answer (score 0):

Nunca terminas de ejecutar Coche(), por lo que nunca asigna las ruedas.

Según el comentario de Triby:
El método constructor no puede tener el mismo nombre de la clase

```
<?php 
class Coche{
    var $ruedas;

    function Coche(){
        $this->ruedas = 4;
    }

    function arrancar(){
        echo "arrancando<br>";
    }
}

$renault=new Coche();
var_dump($renault);
echo "</br>";
$renault->arrancar();
echo $renault->ruedas;
$renault->Coche();
echo $renault->ruedas;
var_dump($renault);
echo "</br>";
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Depende de la versión de PHP que estés ejecutando. Probablemente de 5.4 a 7.X puede funcionar, pero, a partir de 8.0, se genera un mensaje de error `E_DEPRECATED` y será visible dependiendo de la configuración de `display_errors` y `error_reporting`.

Comment: Gracias, que está totalmente obsoleto es lo que quería saber. Estudiaré las nueva forma de usar los constructores.